# Submitting Print ready files

Tags: print-design

I need some help with regards to submitting print ready files:

please help me find solution to list of queries given below:

Software >> Adobe illustrator

Logo Design >>

1) I select colors using HSB slider and create new swatch. Is it correct method to choose colors ?

2) Can I use spot colors (Pantone-solid coated) in the design by adding new swatch. Will it display correctly in PDF, EPS, JPEG and PNG files ?

3) Can I use Gradient or dropshadow in the design. If yes, do we have to flatten it when saving the file as pdf or Vector EPS.

4) I embed ICC Profiles for PDF (i.e,U.S. Web Coated(SWOP) v2 ) and  JPEG (i.e, sRGB IEC61966-2.1) , so that colors display correctly in every other PC.
 Do we have an option to embed profile for  PNG and Vector EPS. Because there is a color shift in vector EPS.

5) Can I set resolution for JPEG and PNG files to 110 DPI INSTEAD OF 72 DPI

Business Card >>

1) I convert Image to CMYK. If the resolution of the image is more than 300dpi do we have to reduce it.

2) Texts are not outlined for Name, Address etc.. do we have to embed font? If not, how is it going to work.

Label or packaging design >>

1) Do we have to use only Pantone colors? If yes will it display correctly in PDF or EPS file?

Comment: There's *way* too much here to answer any of it effectively. You might try searching this site for some answers. Most, if not all, of these topics have been covered before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Ai file is absolutely perfect.
   -Use CYMK colors

2)Pantone is OK It is more reliable. This way you are on the same page with the printer. What pantone color you see on your monitor and what pantone they will see or use in printing.

3)Gradients are ok especially if you give them you full vector. NOT in PDF form because it will be chopped chopped into lines. this also apply in dropshadows.

4) EPS is also ok with your color settings.

5) DPI setting is printers job. You dont have to worry. Just set your resolution in 300ppi. Make sure you give them also the Edittable files for JPEGS PNG or PSD FIles. Just embed them first in illustrator If they want to make it more clear atleast they have the raw files.

6) The Higher resolution the better. But too high because it will have big file size and the prepress will open and close it in slow speed. 300-350 ppi is my recommended settings.

7) a) Outline **ALL** your texts if possible. It will be the **BEST** help you can give  for the Prepress person. It is ok for the Generic fonts like Arial but in some special font you better it will be in outline form because it is already set. b) If you want it Edittable Just keep your a personal copy/backup or **GIVE** all the fonts (.ttf or  softcopy) you use in the artwork.

8) As mentioned PMS or Pantone Matching System is Good because it will as accurate as sharing same monitor to them. We can see it in Pantone colors perfectly if it is in Vector file e.g. AI,PDF, EPS, SVG, .CDR

9) If your affraid for the copyright issue (which i personally Do when designing materials). Set aside it. Prepress people are too busy to copy all files. We appreciate more if you trust us. If we see your artwork is beautiful and Perfectly done,we will try our best to make the print out the best way as you see it. Seeing your good artwork printed good will be our reward as Prepress  designers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dodie :) I think now I can jump into designing more confidently :)